# Can someone help me understand this GPL license

Tags: licensing, gpl

I can't understand the last line of this GPL license.

> Copyright (C) 2011 Some Name
>
> This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
>   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
>   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at
>   your option) any later version. This program is distributed in the
>   hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even
>   the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
>   PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
>
> You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
>   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301
>   USA
>
> Linking SOMEAPP statically or dynamically with other modules is making
>   a combined work based on SOMEAPP. Thus, the terms and conditions of
>   the GNU General Public License cover the whole combination.
>
> **In addition, as a special exception, the copyright holders of SOMEAPP
>   give you permission to combine a portion of SOMEAPP with other binary
>   code ("Program") under any license the copyright holders of Program
>   specified, provided the combined work is produced by SOMEAPP.**

I want to know can I use this code in a shareware application.

Comment: Here is a link to the relavent part of the GPL FAQ http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLIncompatibleLibs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use this code unless your shareware application is also licensed under the GPL.

You could ask the original copyright holder to license the code to you under a different license.